# return list of objects with respected values

Tags: java

I need to create class that should return object which is build from this attributes

```
Object object;
String Name;
String ChildName;
String TagName;
```

The problem here is that I need to return list i.e.
In the list for every object there is name,child ... strings.

How can I do that in java?

Comment: Can a class return a list ? or function returns a list ?

Comment: how looks like your existing code?

Comment: If you need to return everything in the object, why not just return the object itself? Or do you want to return a object, which are built from data in a list? Please, improve your question. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are asking a method that returns List of object with given parameters.Then you can create your class as shown below :

```
public class MyClass {
    Object object;
    String Name;
    String ChildName;
    String TagName;

    // methods
}
```

Then in the other method where you want to return list you can use it as shown :

```
List<MyClass> myMethod() {
  List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();      

  // Do whatever you want.

  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not really sure of what you're asking but here is a list of your objects

```
public class MyObject{
    Object object;
    String name;
    String childName;
    String tagName;

    public MyObject(Object object, String name, String childName, String tagName){
        this.object = object;
        this.name = name;
        this.childName = childName;
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "object:\t" + object.toString() + "\tname:\t" + name + "\tchildName:\t" + childName + "\ttagName:\t" + tagName;
    }
}

static void main(String[] args){
    List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        myList.add(new MyObject(i, i, i, i));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println(myList.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

Also I believe in java, you put your variables and methods in camelCase, i.e. you start with lowercase and for ever new word you put it in uppercase. I think that's why your code is shown with your variables in blue, it's just a standard

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyCustomClass{
   Object obj;
   String Name;
   String ChildName;
   String TagName;
}

Class X{

   public List<MyCustomClass> GetList(){
      List<MyCustomClass> list = new ArrayList<MyCustomClass>();
      MyCustomClass objClass = new MyCustomClass();
      objClass.obj = new Object();
      objClass.Name = "xyz";
      objClass.ChildName = "abc";
      objClass.TagName = "tagg";
      list.add(_objClass);

      //Make new objects of MyCustomClass here and add to the list
      return list;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not use underscores to start your variable names :S

Comment: it depends everyone's style of programming...I usually use underscore to point objects of Classes... like MyCustomClass _myCustomClass.. they remind me the class name while programming

Comment: I believe you only code for yourself? That's perfectly doable without the underscore, just use camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you simply need

declare the class with List returning method of all attributes of this class

```
public class SimpleClass {
    private Object object;
    private String name;
    private String childName;
    private String tagName;

    public SimpleClass(Object object, String name, String childName, String tagName) {
        this.object = object;
        this.name = name;
        this.childName = childName;
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }

    public List getAttributeList(){
        List attributes = new ArrayList();
        attributes.add(object);
        attributes.add(name);
        attributes.add(childName);
        attributes.add(tagName);

        return attributes;
    }
}
```

Or do you need the list of objects SimpleClass?